# Query Performance with and without join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose We have two Tables

**Customers** and **Orders**

Customers Table:-

```
custid  custname
------- ---------
  1     aaa
  2     bbb
  3     ccc
```

Orders Table :-

```
   orderid  custid   date 
  --------  ------   -----
    101        1     2016-03-01
    102        1     2016-03-03
    103        2     2016-03-01
```

Now , we have show customers who have placed no orders

We can do it several ways:-

**1.Without Join**

```
Select custid 
from  Customers 
where custid not in
    (Select custid from Orders)
```

and

**2.With Join**

```
Select C.custid
from Customers C left join Orders O 
on C.custid = O.custid
where O.orderid is null
```

I was asked will there be any performance difference ?if ,which will do better and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both queries are different,so comparison is not valid  ..for the queries to be same/to get same execution plan..

1.Replace `Not IN` in first query with `Not Exists`*

if you do this,you may get same plan  for both queries and same treatment...

*why was `Not IN` asked to be removed,other than the reason it may give you weird results when nulls are involved,can be found from this answer [Not IN vs Not Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Pasting Relevant terms from answer..

> The execution plans may be the same at the moment but if either column is altered in the future to allow NULLs the NOT IN version will need to do more work (even if no NULLs are actually present in the data) and the semantics of NOT IN if NULLs are present are unlikely to be the ones you want anyway.

Comment: `2.Remove where clause in second query` gives wrong results

Comment: they both give same results in OP variant. 2 rows. Without WHERE clause it give 832 row